# Sublime Text 3 - подскажите плагин плавной горизонтальной прокрутки

Tags: sublime-text, sublime-text-3

При окне Sublime Text размером 50% монитора(вертикально) горизонтальная прокрутка перематывает большими кусками - крайне неудобно. Может быть есть плагин для облегчения работы? Спасибо.

Comment: [**Horizontal Scroll**](https://github.com/TheOnlyRew/sublime-horizontal-scroll). Если дефолтные значения не устраивают, меняете значения [**параметра `amount`**](https://github.com/TheOnlyRew/sublime-horizontal-scroll/blob/master/Default%20(Windows).sublime-keymap#L2). Вместо 30 и -30 подставляете предпочтительные для Вас значения — будет прокручиваться, соответственно, быстрее или медленнее. Спасибо.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!